# How do I sort Discord.Collection by keys?

Tags: sorting, discord.js

I have a `Discord.Collection` of key-value pairs that stores the information about the number of commands in folders. It looks something like this:

- `debug` - 2
- `utility` - 2
- `fun` - 3
- `best` - 4
- `replies` - 3

I want to sort the collection by folder names (keys) alphabetically (ascending). However, `Discord.Collection.sort()` sorts ascending by **values**, meaning my output is `debug, utility, fun, replies, best` instead of desired `best, debug, fun, replies, utility` output. Because [`Discord.Collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection) extends `Map`, I looked up [js map documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), but there is no `.sort()` method. I also looked up sorting in StackOverflow and google, but I only found answers regarding value sorting (or answer in different coding language, which I failed to translate).

I know `.sort()` accepts lambda expression as parameter, but I don't know how to use it for key sorting - I only ever used it for value sorting.

I don't think the code is necessary for this question, but in case you need to visualise my problem, here is creation of my collection:

```
const FolderCollection = new Discord.Collection();

//commandList is a Collection of key: command.name, value: {command: command, folder: folder}
commandList.each((cmd) => { 
    if (FolderCollection.has(cmd.folder)) {
        FolderCollection.set(
            cmd.folder,
            FolderCollection.get(cmd.folder) + 1
        );
    } else {
        FolderCollection.set(cmd.folder, 1);
    }
});
```

Here I want to use my sorted FolderCollection:

```
FolderCollection.sort().each((cmdCount, categoryName) => {
            
            //...do stuff
            
        });
```

Feel free to ask for any additional details, but I believe this is all you need to help me with my issue (either direct answer, or link to documentation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Collection#entries()` in a spread operator to turn the collection into an array with the structure `[[key, value]]`, sort *that* because you'll have access to the whole array (key and value), and then convert it back into a collection if needed. Here's an example with a `Map`.

```js
// let's say my objective is to sort these
// from lowest to highest relative to the key
// so the result should be:
// Map (3) { 1 => 'bar', 2 => 'baz', 3 => 'foo' }

const map = new Map([[3, 'foo'], [1, 'bar'], [2, 'baz']]);

// make use of [...iterable] to turn an iterable
// into an array
const entries = [...map.entries()];
console.log('Entries: ', entries);

// use array destructuring to access the
// first element of both arrays
entries.sort(([a], [b]) => a - b);
console.log('Sorted Entries: ', entries);

// convert it back to a map (or collection)
// if needed
const newMap = new Map(entries);
```

Comment: Seeing your answer I assume there is no native way to do it with eg. `.sort()` method?

Comment: I can think of one, but it's, like, twice as complicated and verbose as the one I originally proposed